# How can I create this equivalent list in C#?

Tags: c#, python, list-comprehension

In Python I create a list of upto 10 million elements with this declaration,

```py
res = [0, 1] * (N // 2) + [1]
```

Is there a way to do the equivalent in C# without iterating over the list? I'm trying something like this,

```cs
List<int> res = Enumerable.Repeat(0, N).ToList();
```

But can't quite figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: What is so complicated about `Enumerable.Repeat(elementToRepeat, repeatCount)`? This should work the way you posted it.

Comment: "Without iterating the array" There literally is no array. However your question is quite unclear to me, what difficulties exactly are you struggling? Your syntax seems correct to me, or do ou get an error?

Comment: My understanding of `Enumerable.Repeat` is that it generates a sequence of one repeated value, whereas I'm trying to generate a sequence of two values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a list of alternating 0s and 1s use `Enumerable.Range` and then perform modulo on the result:

```
var N = 10;
var res = Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(x => x % 2);
```

Output:

> 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

---

If you want to repeat an arbitrary sequence, you have to use `Enumerable.Repeat` and then combine the iterators using `SelectMany`:

```
var res = Enumerable.Repeat(new [] {1, 4, 3}, N).SelectMany(x => x);
```

Output:

> 1 4 3 1 4 3 1 4 3 1 4 3 1 4 3 1 4 3 1 4 3 1 4 3 1 4 3 1 4 3

Instead of the array (or list) you could have also put `Enumerable.Range` or any other iterator method:

```
var res = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Range(0,2), N).SelectMany(x => x);
```

which again creates a list of alternating 0s and 1s.

---

To append a single item at the end use `Concat`:

```
var res = Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(x => x % 2).Concat(new [] {1});
```

Output:

> 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1

---

**So basically from Python to C#:**

- `*` → `Enumerable.Repeat`
- `+` → `Enumerable.Concat`
- `[a,b,c]` → `new [] {a,b,c}`